# Tensorflow out of memory when i change my optimizer

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I was training my own tensorflow codes, the following problem happened.
The first time i used the `tf.train.Gradientdescentoptimizer()` to optimize my neural network, everything worked well, but after i changed the optimizer to others, such as `tf.train.adamoptimizer()`, tensorflow showed that :
[OOM when allocating tensor withshapt[50176, 4096]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrOgX.png).

So I tried to decrease my `batch_size` , but even if i changed `batch_size` to `batch_size = 1`, it still can not be fixed.

> When I run this program, I didn't run any others.
>
> The memory of my computer is 8GB, and the memory of my gpu is 6GB.
>
> The version of tensorflow is tensorflow-gpu1.4, operating system is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

So if anyone who has met the same problem, or anybody who has some advice for this problem.  Thank you so much in advance.

**I am not a native English speaker, I am sorry if there are any mistakes in my description.**

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you increase your batch size ?

Comment: I didn't increase my batch size, because it is already out of memory. So I think if i increase my bath size, it will needs more memory.